# Storing images securely, DB vs Encryption on ubuntu.

Tags: mysql, image, ubuntu, encryption

So the current project needs to store images/videos without the possibility of anybody getting access to these images/videos.

Is it possible to store images on a DB, using a `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB` with maybe a base64 encoding and an encryption key?

If it is, is this safer than storing them locally on the disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. MySQL even has built-in support for AES via AES_ENCRYPT(), but it seems to use a block mode of ECB, so you probably don't want to use that (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

A blob datatype would be fine for storing encrypted data. Base64 encoding would be fine but is not necessary (BLOB stores data as byte strings, you'd be performing a lot of unnecessary conversions).

Search around, you'll likely find plenty of posts about encrypting images.

As to whether it is SAFER or not, I'm not sure if you're still talking about encrypting the images on disk or leaving them unencrypted. I can't speak to this with any degree of certainty, but I can't think of any particular increase in security you might gain from storing them in a database (encrypted) over storing them on disk (encrypted).

Comment: sounds good to me, so i'll look into encrypting images a little more